# Some images do not load and they are all in the same folder : Angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, deployd

I have a mysterious problem. I made an Angularjs app on localhost and it works fine so far. I transferred it to a server and not all images get loaded. Some do. There is no difference at all , they are the same type of .jpg images and sit in the same folder. I am reading pro angular from A. Freeman and that's why I use Deployd for the database work. I am not sure if I may give the website address but that's the best way to show you.

http://h2384839.stratoserver.net:5000/test.html

If you click on "Winkelen" (that's Dutch for shopping) you will see the problem. I tried to debug in Chrome's devtools but it really should work. I can't find the reason why it does not work with the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found your problem. Your problem is the extension. Try JPG instead of jpg and you will see the images will load. Extensions are case sensitive so make sure they are set correctly :)

You could rename all the files to have small ".jpg" extension. You could use the Command prompt directly to rename the files for example :

```
rename shandy.JPG shandy.jpg
```

Comment: src is hard coded with the full url. And it is the right one.

Comment: How do you preload images? They are already on the server in the images folder

Comment: I faced same problem when I was dynamically setting the SRC tag to an image depending on some condition. By preload I meant statically setting the image in the page somewhere and then render it(show) when needed.

Comment: Please check my answer, just found your problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. I watched in fiddler.
   your image url responce using Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
   change it to Content-Type   image/jpeg.
2. And check images in server

Comment: can you tell me how to that? But I don't understand why some images are loaded succesfully.